# Issue with a method of animation in an Android project - Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm testing a small animation example on Android studio. On the last method 'toggle' I'm getting an error Cannot resolve symbol views. Can someone help me to fix this issue?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ViewGroup viewGroup;
private TextView textView;
private ImageView imageView, imageView2, imageView3,imageView4,imageView7;
private Button button;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewGroup=(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.viewGroup);
    textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("It's animating");
    imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView2= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageView3= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    imageView4= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    imageView7= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);


  button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickme);
  button.setText("Done");

   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View v) {
         TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(viewGroup, new Explode());
         toggle(textView, imageView, imageView2, imageView3, imageView4, imageView7);
     }
   });


              private static void toggle(View... views) {
                  for (View v : views) {
                      boolean isVisible = v.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
                      v.setVisibility(isVisible ? View.INVISIBLE :
                              View.VISIBLE);
                  }
              }
}}
```

Comment: if you set `for (views)` then ??